# span monitors:i:1 or /span not working with RDP on one machine

Tags: multiple-monitors, remote-desktop, windows-server-2016

We are trying to connect a hyper-V VM running Windows Server 2016 version 1607 that needs to connect with the resolution 3840x1080 from a PC with two 1920x1080 monitors. The 2 monitors should act as one big monitor.

We have successfully accomplished this before using `span monitors:i:1` on many other machines. However this one either only want to work as two screens with `use multimon:i:1` or in windowed mode with the resolution set to 3840x1080.

We have tried:

- Play around with "screen mode id"
- Changed the resolution
- Tried turning `use multimon` on and off
- Manually set `selectedmonitors:s:0,1`

None of them have worked. Do you have any ideas?

RDP settings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfWj5.png

mstsc /l: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlG7s.png

Comment: Could you [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1625517/edit) into your post the contents of the `.rdp` file, and also the output of `mstsc.exe /l`.

Comment: Hi @harrymc the .rdp settings and mstsc /l are now added as images in the post

Comment: First, posting the `.rdp` file as text would have been better. Second, multiple errors: (1) The two local monitors are at 2560x1440, not 1920x1080. (2) Try setting `span monitors:i:1`. (3) Missing `selectedmonitors:s:0,1` (4) `desktopwidth` and `desktopheight` describe the remote session and not the local computer.

Comment: @harrymc (1) never mind the resolution on the screenshotted `.rdp` file. The VM we are having problems with is a customer server which i do not have access to at the time. The rest of the settings are the same (2) `span monitors:i:1` is at the bottom (3) the result is the same regardless of `selectedmonitors:s:0,1` (4) from my tests on other machines (that works) `desktopwidth` and `desktopheight` doesn't matter if `span monitors:i:1` is on

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently.  It turned out that there was a problem with drag and drop on the client RDP machine (preventing the span option from launching correctly).  A simple press of the escape key while attempting to drag an icon in Explorer solved the issue for me (in Win10 Enterprise 21H2).